# In selenium webdriver, how do i switch my control to div element which have complete form

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application, when i sign up successfully, one pop up form is open which is a div element, div contain some form fields. Now i want to switch my control to div and enter values to each field and submit the form.
How can i do this?
I have used below code

```
String parentwindowhandler= drive.getWindowHandle(); // store your parent window..
String subwindowhandler=null;
Set<String> handles= drive.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator= handles.iterator(); 
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    subwindowhandler= iterator.next();
}
drive.switchTo().window(subwindowhandler); // switch to child window..
```

Comment: Generally speaking, a new <div> is not a new page or frame.  It's usually code that is simply not displayed until activated and the elements are contained on the same page of HTML.  It can be an Alert or it can simply be the appearance of a new window.  I'm guessing a new tab does not open up in this case?  There should be no need to switch windows in this scenario.  Please show some of the HTML code.

Comment: you need to post your HTML Code there might be iframes at the play

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you don't need to switch control to a DIV once you are in the same window. You just get the `WebElement` for instance by id

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("element id"));
```

and then send your text with `sendKeys()` or click with `click()`.

Instead of `By.id` you can also use `By.name`, `By.xpath`..., but using ids is the safest.